# Can't set Google Account Credential in Android

Tags: android, rest, credentials, drive

I'm trying to use the Google Drive REST API - using the exact sample code found at [Android REST Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android).  However I cannot set an account name for the Google Account Credential object in the the `onActivityResult` method.

I don't get it as I've triple checked that `mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);` is definitely being passed an email string for the account name, but when I try and use `mCredential.getSelectedAccountName()` it always returns null immediately after it has supposedly been set.  This means that the account picker is constantly being called but never sets an account name.

Someone please help as this is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1):

If You are running your application on android version 6.+ then make sure that your app has all the required permission allowed. You can check this by going Setting->apps->your_app->apps permission.